# Fields with source property != influenced property?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

As far as I know, a field (gravitational, electric, magnetic) is created by something (mass, charge, moving charge) and can exert a force on something (a mass, charge, moving charge).

Is there a (good) reason why the field source and the "acted upon" property are always the same? Are there fields where this assumption does not hold?

**Update:**
I think that Newton III (actio = reactio) might be a good reason why there is no field as described above.

Assume a massless particle that is affected by earth's gravity. There would be a force on the particle due to the gravitational field, but no "reactio", because the particle itself does not have a gravitational field that would act on the earth.

Did I just answer my own question?